# Can't register the minion on salt-master

Tags: saltstack

I'm trying to connect salt-minion to the Salt master. But it doesn't work. Where is the mistake
what is wrong?

ping from Master server to minion server works and vice versa too

here are the logs:

**

### Minion Logs:

**

***nc -v -z 176.111.111 4505***

```
nc: connect to 176.111.111 port 4505 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

***salt-minion -l debug***

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: test.com
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Minion " test.com "
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'base64_encode' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'base64_decode' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'md5' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'sha1' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'sha256' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'sha512' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'hmac' as a jinja filter
[DEBUG   ] Marking 'hmac_compute' as a jinja filter

[DEBUG   ] Created pidfile: /var/run/salt-minion.pid
[INFO    ] Starting up the Salt Minion
[DEBUG   ] AsyncEventPublisher PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ga7823F_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] AsyncEventPublisher PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[INFO    ] Starting pull socket on /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Grains refresh requested. Refreshing grains.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'core' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'disks' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'extra' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'lvm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'mdadm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'minion_process' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'opts' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] Override  __utils__: <module 'salt.loaded.int.grains.zfs' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/grains/zfs.py'>
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded zfs.is_supported
[INFO    ] Creating minion process manager
[DEBUG   ] Process Manager starting!
[DEBUG   ] Process Manager starting!
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp://176.111.111.111:4506
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', 'test.com', 'tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (10564)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '10564ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt._get_key_with_evict: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
[ERROR   ] Error while bringing up minion for multi-master. Is master at 176.111.111.111responding?
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506
[DEBUG   ] Re-using AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', ‚test.com‘, 'tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (9944)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '9944ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Minion unable to successfully connect to a Salt Master.
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
[ERROR   ] Error while bringing up minion for multi-master. Is master at 176.111.111.111 responding?
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506
[DEBUG   ] Re-using AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', ‚test.com, 'tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (5633)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '7145ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[DEBUG   ] Closing AsyncReqChannel instance
^C[DEBUG   ] Closing IPCMessageSubscriber instance
[WARNING ] Minion received a SIGINT. Exiting.
[INFO    ] Shutting down the Salt Minion
```

***salt-call -l debug state.apply***

```
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] Using cached minion ID from /etc/salt/minion_id: minion.com
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Grains refresh requested. Refreshing grains.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] Including configuration from '/etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf'
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion.d/uyuni.conf
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'core' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'disks' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'extra' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'lvm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'mdadm' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'minion_process' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'opts' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] Override  __utils__: <module 'salt.loaded.int.grains.zfs' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/grains/zfs.py'>
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] The functions from module 'zfs' are being loaded by dir() on the loaded module
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded zfs.is_supported
[DEBUG   ] Connecting to master. Attempt 1 of 1
[DEBUG   ] Master URI: tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncAuth for ('/etc/salt/pki/minion', ‚ ‚minion.com‘, 'tcp:// 176.111.111.111:4506')
[DEBUG   ] Generated random reconnect delay between '1000ms' and '11000ms' (1892)
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl to '1892ms'
[DEBUG   ] Setting zmq_reconnect_ivl_max to '11000ms'
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_key: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt._get_key_with_evict: Loading private key
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_ ga7823F _pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] salt.crypt.get_rsa_pub_key: Loading public key
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
[ERROR   ] Failed to send msg SaltReqTimeoutError('Message timed out',)
```

Ports on master-server 4505 and 4506 are opened

Many Thanks

Comment: if you get 'nc: connect to 176.111.111 port 4505 (tcp) failed: No route to host' then you need to fix this first. Obviously the ip address is wrong, but you should not see this message.